# Where did the rest of Walter White's money go?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, part of Walter's money got absorbed by the Gray Matter corporation that will be later handed out to Walter's family.

But what happens to the remaining money he has made?

Comment: You mean the money Jack and his gang took? No one knows. A dying Jack tries to bait Walt with the information, but Walt kills him. He doesn't care.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson More than possible, I'd say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the episode "To'hajiilee," most of the money is taken by Neo-Nazis. Walter spends some of the rest while he is in hiding, more on his "revenge" apparatus, and gives the rest to Gray Matter to be disbursed to his family at a later date.

We never find out what happens to the millions that the Neo-Nazis stole. In the final episode of the series, Walter is given the chance to (maybe) find out but, perhaps because he is badly wounded, does not take that opportunity.